# Cypress can't bypass login page with Cognito authorization

Tags: authorization, cypress, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm getting Cognito credentials with custom command:

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";
Cypress.Commands.add("loginByCognitoApi", () => {
      //configures auth
    const awsconfig = {
      aws_user_pools_id: Cypress.env("userPoolId"),
      aws_user_pools_web_client_id: Cypress.env("clientId"),
    };
    Auth.configure(awsconfig);
    //sign in
    const signIn = Auth.signIn(Cypress.env("username"), Cypress.env("password"));
    //get the tokens and store into the local storage
    cy.wrap(signIn, { log: false }).then((cognitoResponse) => {
      const keyPrefixWithUsername = `${cognitoResponse.keyPrefix}.${cognitoResponse.username}`;
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.idToken`,
        cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken,
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.accessToken`,
        cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken,
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.refreshToken`,
        cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.refreshToken.token,
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        `${keyPrefixWithUsername}.clockDrift`,
        cognitoResponse.signInUserSession.clockDrift,
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        `${cognitoResponse.keyPrefix}.LastAuthUser`,
        cognitoResponse.username,
      );
      window.localStorage.setItem("amplify-authenticator-authState", "signedIn");
      console.log(localStorage)
    }) 

});
```

[authorization data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px6fq.png)
After cy.visit() all storage is cleared and redirects back to login screen
Please, advise what could be wrong. Thank you!

Expected: bypass login page
Actual: redirects back to login page

Comment: Please try to provide a bit more context on how you are using such custom command. Keep in mind that from [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage): "Cypress automatically clears all local storage before each test to prevent state from being shared across tests when test isolation is enabled."

Comment: @ammendonca I'm trying to avoid typing login credentials before each test, therefore getting authorization from cognito, saving it to local storage and trying access different pages of application, but getting redirected to login anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Follow this example: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/amazon-cognito-authentication